# Hostapd and dnsmasq are set up but i dont get any signal on my devices

Tags: pi-3, raspbian-stretch, access-point, hostapd

i have set up hostapd and dnsmasq and ran into some issues. at first the issue was that hostapd didn't recognized the driver. after i deleted that line it did start up. then dnsmasq told me that there was an invalid option in the /etc/dnsmasq.conf which was the "listen-address" option. after deleting that line dnsmasq started up aswell and both services are running. but the problem i have now is that i don't get any signal to my devices. it should normally show the ssid "WiPi-Repeater" but i don't get any signal. i am using:

- Raspberry Pi 3 Model B
- TP-Link Archer T2U wifi dongle
- 2019-04-08-raspbian-stretch-full image.

I hope you guys can help me because i haven't found anything according to my problem yet.

Here is the hostapd.conf:

```
interface=wlan1

hw_mode=g
channel=6
ieee80211n=1
wmm_enabled=1
ht_capab=[HT40][SHORT-GI-20][DSSS_CCK-40]
macaddr_acl=0
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0

auth_algs=1
wpa=2
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
rsn_pairwise=CCMP

ssid=WiPi-Repeater
wpa_passphrase=mypassword
```

and here the dnsmasq.conf:

```
interface=wlan1
bind-interfaces
server=8.8.8.8
domain-needed
bogus-priv
dhcp-range=192.168.178.50,192.168.178.150,12h
```

if i use `sudo systemctl is-active dnsmasq` and `sudo systemctl is-active hostapd` both are marked as `enabled`

for the `lsusb` command i get:

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 148f:761a Ralink Technology, Corp.
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 1a2c:0e24 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 145f:01de Trust
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMC9514 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

and for `lsmod`:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
fuse                  110592  3
rfcomm                 49152  4
bnep                   20480  2
hci_uart               36864  1
btbcm                  16384  1 hci_uart
serdev                 20480  1 hci_uart
bluetooth             368640  29 hci_uart,bnep,btbcm,rfcomm
ecdh_generic           28672  1 bluetooth
ipt_MASQUERADE         16384  1
nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4    16384  1 ipt_MASQUERADE
iptable_nat            16384  1
nf_nat_ipv4            16384  1 iptable_nat
nf_nat                 28672  2 nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4,nf_nat_ipv4
nf_conntrack_ipv4      16384  3
nf_defrag_ipv4         16384  1 nf_conntrack_ipv4
xt_conntrack           16384  1
nf_conntrack          126976  6 nf_conntrack_ipv4,ipt_MASQUERADE,nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4,xt_conntrack,nf_nat_ipv4,nf_nat
iptable_filter         16384  1
evdev                  24576  8
joydev                 20480  0
mt7610u               688128  1
brcmfmac              307200  0
brcmutil               16384  1 brcmfmac
snd_bcm2835            32768  1
snd_pcm                98304  1 snd_bcm2835
cfg80211              573440  2 mt7610u,brcmfmac
snd_timer              32768  1 snd_pcm
rfkill                 28672  8 bluetooth,cfg80211
snd                    69632  5 snd_timer,snd_bcm2835,snd_pcm
fixed                  16384  0
uio_pdrv_genirq        16384  0
uio                    20480  1 uio_pdrv_genirq
i2c_dev                16384  0
ip_tables              24576  2 iptable_filter,iptable_nat
x_tables               32768  4 ip_tables,iptable_filter,ipt_MASQUERADE,xt_conntrack
ipv6                  425984  28
```

If you need any more details i can give them but i guess i gave the most details.  The only thing like i said is only that i don't get any SSID shown on my devices.

here are the Supported interface mode for Wiphy phy1 aswell:

```
Supported interface modes:
                 * IBSS
                 * managed
                 * AP
                 * P2P-client
                 * P2P-GO
                 * P2P-device
```

**Update:**
I wanted to repeat the connection from onboard to dongle. but since it won't let me do it and it doesn't show me an AP i can't repeat the wifi connection. what i can't do is that i would go from eth0 to wlan0 because i have no wired connection to repaeat since my rpi is going to be in the staircase. if i would find the driver that is installed for the wifi dongle i have i would try to use that for hostapd but yeah... idk where to find it.

Comment: Please check the output of `iw phy | less`. You will get a buch of information. Scroll to the section starting with `Wiphy phy1` (not using `phy0`). Within this section select the subsection starting with `Supported interface modes:`. Please edit your question and copy and paste the listed modes into it.

Comment: @Ingo i edited the post. at the bottom you can find the `supported interface modes` for `Wiphy phy1`

Answer (score 1):

My first guess was that the *TP-Link Archer T2U wifi dongle* does not support an access point but with your update you show that it does with mode `AP`. Another possible problem could be the driver for the USB/wifi dongle. You wrote that hostapd didn't recognized the driver. Seems hostapd now starts with its default driver but that does not fit to the dongle.

You are using a Raspberry Pi 3B with an on-board wifi device. That is known to work with default Raspbian and **hostpad** by many tutorials. Just to verify I suggest to pull out the USB/wifi dongle and setup the access point with the on-board wifi device represented with interface **wlan0**.

**Update:**
As far as I understand now from your update, you want to configure a wifi repeater. You can do it only with the on-board wifi device. You do not need two physical interfaces. The RasPi can make a client connection to your remote hotspot and simultaneously create an access point. Just pull out the problematic USB/WiFi dongle. You don't need it. Look at [Access point as WiFi repeater, optional with bridge](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/89804/79866) how to setup it.

Comment: If i would do that i will need a wired connection which would not be possyble since i have no actual connection to the router. the only way i can achieve my goal is if i use a wifi dongle. i have another wifi dongle aswell from Sitecom but that one isn't even getting recognised and i couldn't find any drivers for that one. what i wonder is how i can see the drivers from my **wlan0** and **wlan1** devices. `lsmod` doesn't show me anything understandable for me.

Comment: @MistralDreamer I do not understand your problem. Why do you need a wired connection **eth0**  together with **wlan0**? What is the difference between the on-board device and the USB/WiFi dongle? Why do you do not need a wired connection with the dongle?

Comment: Well, i wanted to repeat the connection from onboard to dongle. but since it won't let me do it and it doesn't show me an AP i can't repeat the wifi connection. what i can't do is that i would go from **eth0** to **wlan0** because i have no wired connection to repaeat since my rpi is going to be in the staircase. if i would find the driver that is installed for the wifi dongle i have i would try to use that for hostapd but yeah... idk where to find it.

Comment: @MistralDreamer I have updated the answer with the last paragraph.